# [UICachedDeviceRGBColor stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I've this error, when I try to use `UIColor` : [UICachedDeviceRGBColor stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',   reason: '-[UICachedDeviceRGBColor stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f957952d870'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103363d85 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102ac7deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010336cd3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001032b2cfa ___forwarding_** + 970

Comment: Also show the code that you have try.

Comment: you are try to change the color string

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Answer (score 0):

The crash log says that you try send message to `UICachedDeviceRGBColor` class but it doesn't have method with name `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` and it doesn't inherit from `NSString`. This method declare only in `NSString` class.